# Difference between Grandma and Grandma-ma?

Tags: meaning, grammar, etymology

This is my first question here so please be gentle with me. I have a relative staying with me from Mississippi who says things about manners and behavior in reference to his grandma-ma. It goes a little like.

> My grandma-ma always said X.

or

> My grandma-ma raised me better than to do X.

Now I've just kind of assumed that grandma-ma was a southern way of saying grandma but recently I've been lead to believe that it refers to a great-grandmother.

Sadly my relative has continued their travels and I don't have a way of touching base with them to ask.

Can someone explain to me this difference and maybe include a source where I can find out more about how it came to be. Running a google search on this kind of took me to a bunch of places that didn't answer my question.

Comment: Is that hyphen significant? Did your relative actually pronounce it as ‘grand-mama’ /ˈɡɹæ̃mɑːmə ~ ˈɡɹæ̃məmə/, i.e., with the same stress pattern as ‘grandmother’? Or did he pronounce like the word ‘grandma’ with an added ‘ma’ on the end, so /ˈɡɹæ̃mɑː.ˈmɑː/? I’m not sure if there’s a difference, but _if_ there is, I would be quite likely to interpret the latter as referring to a great-grandmother (a ‘grandma[’s] ma’) and the former as a grandmother (a ‘grand mama’).

Comment: Pet names for grandparents are highly variable, in time and in place. For grandmother we have grandma, gramma, mee-maw, bubby, bubbe... these are just a few that I have heard in my life at different times and in different places; I suspect there are many, many more. I would distrust what any central source had to say, and would instead ask people who lived in the same time and place as your relative.

Comment: "Grandma" vs "Grandmama" could also be a family-specific distinction. I've known families where the father and son both have the same name (e.g. James) but one goes by a nickname (e.g. Jim). There's no "standard" for how the nicknames are decided; it's up to the families and individual people involved. So maybe once "Mama" became a grandma, it became necessary to call great-grandma something else... or maybe great-grandma always went by "Grandmama" in her older years because that's what her young grandchildren called her. There's a story behind everything!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet no the hyphen is not significant. It's just the way I wrote it. It is was pronounced like "granmama" but I just figured it'd be spelled in the way I listed it in my question. Should I edit my question?

Comment: There are two main possibilities.  1) "Grandmama" is simply "baby talk" for "grandma" -- a family's term of affection.  2) "Grandmama" is intended to mean "great grandmother".  Many languages and dialects have such contrived terms for great grandparents.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I’m wondering whether his hyphenation mightn’t indicate something else in the third syllable than was in the second, perhaps [ˈɡɹæ̃məˌmɞ̞], which some rounding on that final syllable’s centralized vowel, the way you hear something of that in the [*meemaw*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meemaw#English) of the American Deep South.  But maybe I’m more thinking of French *grand-maman* [ɡʁɑ̃mamɑ̃] here.

Comment: @HotLicks only two possibilities? I don't think I know two families who call their grandparents the same thing, frankly _within_ the same family.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

" **Grandmama** is an archaic form of grandma according to the http://www.oxforddictionaries.com which is is another name for a grandmother, or the mother of one's father or mother.""a grandmother; an old woman"", from ""grand"" (adjective) + ""dame"".

An interesting etymology of the word 'mama'. 1707, spelling variant of mamma. Meaning ""sexually attractive woman"" first recorded 1925 in African-American vernacular; mama's boy ""soft, effeminate male"" is from 1901. Hve a look at http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mama
But the word Grandmama was dated by 1749.

Answer (score 4):

Many of my extended family members, in the North of Yorkshire, used grandma for their mother's mother and grandmama for their father's mother. I have heard of other people using variations on this to differentiate between paternal and maternal grandparents.

Answer (score 0):

Simply meant Grandmother in my Georgia, southern family.
I feel certain this must have been the same for your friend.

Comment: The other answers already cover this, though...